# Text use minimum space in Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Here is my code:

```kotlin
Row {
    Text(
        text = text1,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp))
    Text(
        text = text2,
        maxLines = 1,
    )
}
```

The text2's length is short (but not specical width) while text1's length may be long or short. I want text2 always visible and text1 shows ellipsis when it is long.

The `Modifier.weight(1F)` can't meet my requirement because text1 will
fill up the remaining space and text2 always at the end of `Row`. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the parameter `fill = false`, if you don't want `weigth` to fill the remaining space.

```
Row {
    Text(
        text = text1,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f, fill = false)
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp))
    Text(
        text = text2,
        maxLines = 1,
    )
}
```

In this way, when `text1` is short it will take the minimum space it needs, and when `text1` is long it will fill as much as it can. In both cases `text2` will still take its own space and remain visible.